# How do I know if an user is dead or alive, when an user didn't accept my answer can a admin verify and accept it?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, unaccepted-answer

For instance, I am posting an answer for a question asked by an user. His last seen shows that 7months ago. I can come to a conclusion that he is not active in stack exchange any more. If he is alive he will return some day but if he is not alive (May his soul rest in peace) but **do stack exchange knows if he is dead or alive?** If it comes to know the user no longer exists in this world then why not admin can verify and accept my answer?

Forgive me if I sound rude!

Comment: I can see users being emotional rather than intellectual and just hitting downvotes..crazy!

Comment: This question is so strange that I initially edited it to replace all instances of 'alive' with 'active', because I assumed you were talking about that .... How exactly should SO know which users are deceased?

Comment: WHY not and its not a rocket science. How do users would trust an answer when it's not accepted? When those users are in the same shoes of the user who is no longer exists...

Comment: No, all SO needs to do is make it mandatory for relatives to report deaths. Or maybe SO can access the "government death certificate API" of 250 governments? Or do we need to send out emails every week "If you are still alive, please respond!" ....

Comment: *"How do users would trust an answer when it's not accepted?"* Because **accepted does not mean correct.** That's what community voting is for. Accepted just means "the most helpful answer for the OP in solving the OP's problem".

Comment: "How do users would trust an answer when it's not accepted?" That's a fallacy. Accepted means "this answer was most useful to OP", it does not mean "this is the very best answer to the question which is guaranteed to help everyone or at least a majority of other users". You should always check by yourself if an answer works for you, not blindly chase the checkmark.

Comment: Integrating "government death certificate API" of 250 governments would be a good employment opportunity.

Comment: Unfortunately, check marks are most trusted and everyone knows that here... (but I have used unchecked answers as well... ) Why do SO holds the checked answer at the top?

Comment: Why would anyone give particularly high weight to check marks? The check mark is just one person's opinion of the answer. That person had to ask the question, and so may not be particularly expert in its topic.

Comment: If the OP does not check the answer themselves, the check no longer has any meaning at all, and actually becomes misleading.

Comment: "I can see users being emotional" Speak for yourself.

Comment: I'm beginning to really wonder what inspired your name...

Comment: ^ did you call these two diamonds dumbs?

Comment: Note on downvoting - on feature requests it is common to vote according to whether you like the proposed feature. I don't, because it conflicts with the concept of the "accept" being the OP's personal report of which answer, if any, helped them most.

Comment: @BoltClock this should actually be [meta-tag:status-deferred]. I mean, this is most likely next change to be implemented right after Stack Overflow finally gets [direct-to-brain interface](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21053/165773)

Comment: @gnat That's coming in like, 6-8 weeks, right?

Answer (score 39):

We cannot, and will not, place acceptance marks on behalf of anyone else, regardless of whether or not they are still active on the site.

If a user is no longer with us then it is all the more disrespectful to act on their behalf.

Whether you choose to accept this answer or not is, likewise, up to you. I doubt you will, judging by your responses, [but that's none of my business](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/but-thats-none-of-my-business). After all, if we did honor your feature request, someone will eventually mark my answer as accepted anyway (even though doing so would contradict my answer).

Comment: And if you didn't mean to sound rude, that's OK. Only if you didn't mean to.

Comment: Yay! Reversal :)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion In all honesty, not very hard to get on Meta.

Answer (score 13):

[A user is in no way required to accept or even read your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) regardless of whether their account still active or not.

Moreover, *the whole idea behind StackExchange* is posting answers that potentially *benefit further readers as well* rather than just the OP and getting rep *from the users you helped*.

So,

- If the user is no longer active, you didn't help them so there's no reason to accept the answer
- Asking anyone to accept an answer on another's behalf is out of question at SE
- The SE system is made so that if your answer is useful enough, it should gain you rep regardless

---

...If you think about it, **the "accept an answer on another's behalf" is not so out of question, theoretically...** We simply need to maintain that you "helped" the person accepting, too. So, one could possibly "take over" the quesiton... and voila! Right?

Maybe. Because we also need to justify you getting more rep than for an upvote. What can that be (specifically, why does an acceptance give more rep in the first place?)?

- the OP asked the question, thus giving you a chance to earn some rep in the first place (but that's a reward for them). You helped them more than other upvoters by giving an answer *tailored for their specific needs.* Then the other person should have *exactly* the same needs.
- the tick signifies that

  - the answer fully resolves the matter at hand rather than just "being useful" (a direct quotation from the upvote link's popup tip)
  - the problem outlined in the question has been resolved

  For this, no one is qualified to make these statements except the OP and, again, someone with exactly the same problem.

**So, we need a way to**

- identify someone with exactly the same need (which includes providing objective proof of that), and
- justify them being qualified to operate the original question (rather than their own one if they posted a duplicate, for example). E.g. should they also qualify to be targeted by further votes? What about the original author?

I've no idea how we can possibly do this, so, if you're so much interested in seeing this implementing, it's up to you from here.